# Ensuring that all fields of a class are serialized

Tags: c++, serialization, boost-serialization

I am writing serialize / de-serialize methods on an existing C++ class that contains several fields where most of these fields are complex, nested data structures themselves. What are some techniques I could use to ensure that I had serialized all the fields? I am using the Boost serialization library for this project.

One method I can think of is to write an 'equal' function for all the data types and write unit-tests that would assert that the original object was equal to the de-serialized object. However, this method seems error prone since amongst other things, the equals function would require an update whenever a field was added to the data type.